# Iterate through a list of strings from a column in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing a list of words in the 'Message' column. How do i iterate through the list of strings from the column to apply a function that i created to correct the spelling?

I already have the function for the correction ready.

```
def correct_spelling(data):
w = Word(data) 
correct_word = (w.correct())
return correct_word



df['Message'] = correct_spelling(df['Message'])
```

INITIAL DATAFRAME

S/No Month Message

0    June    [hey, howw, are, yyou, doing, today, i...]

1    August  [sally, thinks, that, this, jobb, is, easyy...]

2    February [trry, to, buiy, him, a, neow, watch... ]

3    December [i, have, twp, much, taime, on, my, hand... ]

FINAL DATAFRAME

S/No Month Message

0    June    [hey, how, are, you, doing, today, i...]

1    August  [sally, thinks, that, this, job, is, easy...]

2    February [try, to, buy, him, a, new, watch... ]

3    December [i, have, two, much, time, on, my, hand... ]

Comment: `df['Message'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda x: correct_spelling(x))` ?

Comment: I was given the following error. 
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: didnot notice you message is a list, `df['Message'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda x:  [correct_spelling(y) for y in x])`, check Jezrael answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need processing each word separately use:

```
df['Message'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda x: [correct_spelling(y) for y in x])
```

If possible pass list:

```
df['Message'] = df['Message'].apply(correct_spelling)
```